# how to prevent android from getting popup as open app when this usb device is connected or close popup automatically

Tags: android

After device is rebooted.

Prompt appears saying: "Open appName when this USB device is connected?" when the device is rebooted
Press cancel -> app stays open | press okay -> app restarts

Required behaviour: The app either does not show the dialog or automatically click cancel/ok on the pop up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZwD8.png)

can some one help me with the solution for app either does not show the dialog or automatically click cancel/ok on the pop up

Comment: Do you have root on the device or can sign your app with system certificate?

Comment: No, i don't have root on the device@LevM.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about this popup as a regular app.

Only system app - an app that is signed with system certificate or is located in `/system/priv-app` folder in ROM, can bypass this kinds of dialogs.

Since you stated in the comments you do not have root and your app is not a system app, it can not dismiss or prevent showing this dialog.